# How can I get supabase auth user data on my tRPC context?

Tags: next.js, supabase, trpc, t3

I'm making an application using the [t3](https://create.t3.gg/) stack: next, prisma, tRPC. I'm following along with a certain [tutorial](https://youtu.be/YkOSUVzOAA4?t=5047) that uses Clerk for auth and I'm using Supabase Auth instead. In the file where I define my tRPC procedure (i.e. setting up `createTRPCContext`) I need to get access to session data in my tRPC context which I can then pass through into my tRPC router. The author of the tutorial does this with Clerk's `getAuth`, but it's unclear how to do this with supabase.

The docs recommend using `await supabase.auth.getSession();` to get session data. But in order to create an instance of `supabase` I figured I can either use the provided hooks or `createServerSupabaseClient` method. Hooks won't work because it's not a React component/hook; `createServerSupabaseClient` won't work because I need to pass something into it. It also seems strange that I should instantiate another supabase instance.

What's the right way to get the user session data in my tRPC procedure?

Answer (score 2):

you need the context https://trpc.io/docs/context#inner-and-outer-context.

in trpc, you have inner context and outer context, so you can get the nextjs api context

```
// server/trpc.ts

// inner context
interface CreateInnerContextOptions extends Partial<CreateNextContextOptions> {
supabase: SupabaseClient | null;
}

// outer context
export async function createContextInner(opts?: CreateInnerContextOptions) {
    return {
        supabase: opts?.supabase as SupabaseClient<Database> ?? null,
    };
}

export async function createContext(opts: CreateNextContextOptions) {
    const supabase = createPagesServerClient<Database>(opts);
    const contextInner = await createContextInner({ supabase });
    return {
        ...contextInner,
        req: opts.req,
        res: opts.res,
    };
}
export type Context = inferAsyncReturnType<typeof createContextInner>;

//standard trpc declaration and passing context type 
const t = initTRPC.context<Context>().create()
```

and pass the createContext

```
// [trpc].ts
export default trpcNext.createNextApiHandler({
    router: appRouter,
    createContext
});
```

then you can consume the context like

```
// [trpc].ts
publicProcedure.input( ...).mutation(async({input, ctx}) => {
const supabase = ctx.supabase
...rest of the code
```

Comment: this should be acceped as answer